How do I make KEDA use the service account of my application instead of the default one?
I am trying to set up KEDA in my AKS cluster. I have an application running in a pod. I am using workload identity. Everything is set up correctly in that respect, because all the other Azure services work (send and receiving messages service bus, blob storage, key vault, etc.)
Now when I install KEDA using the az az aks update --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --enable-keda command, it successfully runs and I see KEDA pods running in the kube-system namespace.
Then I see the following error message appearing in the logs of the KEDA operator pod: "error_description\": \"AADSTS700213: No matching federated identity record found for presented assertion subject 'system:serviceaccount:kube-system:keda-operator'. Please check your federated identity credential Subject, Audience and Issuer against the presented assertion.
I checked the service account template of my application, and that looks fine.
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    azure.workload.identity/client-id: xxx
    azure.workload.identity/tenant-id: xxx
  name: xxx-sa
  namespace: xxx
  labels:
    app-name: xxx

The templates of the scaled object and trigger authentication also look fine I believe:
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: scaling-trigger-auth
  namespace: xxx
spec:
  podIdentity:
    provider: azure-workload
    identityId: xxx

---

apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: xxx-scaledobject
  namespace: xxx
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: Deployment
    name: xxx-deployment
  minReplicaCount: 1
  maxReplicaCount: 10
  triggers:
    - type: azure-servicebus
      metadata:
        namespace: xxx.servicebus.windows.net
        queueName: xxx
        messageCount: "5"
      authenticationRef:
        name: scaling-trigger-auth

I also uninstalled and installed KEDA, but same issue.
I checked the subject identifier of the managed ID I want to use, and that is different from the subject identifier shown in the error message. I do want to use the managed ID I created for the application, instead of some KEDA managed ID that I need to make.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

you need to configure KEDA to use your custom service account that has the necessary workload identity annotations. edit the default one using kubectl get deployment keda-operator -n kube-system -o yaml > keda-operator-deployment.yaml then add the service account name and annotations for workload identity. something like this-  serviceAccountName: my-service-account (whatever is your custom service account name) TriggerAuthentication and ScaledObject looks good.

To make KEDA use the service account of your application instead of the default one, you need to use federated identity credentials
Create a Federated Identity Credential for the KEDA Operator

Update the KEDA operator's service account to include the required annotations for workload identity.
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: keda-operator
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    azure.workload.identity/client-id: <YOUR_CLIENT_ID>
    azure.workload.identity/tenant-id: <YOUR_TENANT_ID>


Configure the TriggerAuthentication Resource
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: scaling-trigger-auth
  namespace: <YOUR_NAMESPACE>
spec:
  podIdentity:
    provider: azure-workload
    identityId: <YOUR_CLIENT_ID>


Once restart the KEDA operator to ensure it picks up the new service account settings

Another approach involves updating the KEDA operator's deployment to ensure it uses the custom service account with the necessary annotations.
kubectl get deployment keda-operator -n kube-system -o yaml > keda-operator-deployment.yaml

and edit it
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keda-operator
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keda-operator
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keda-operator
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: keda-operator  # Add this line
      containers:
      - name: keda-operator
        image: ghcr.io/kedacore/keda:2.0.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        - containerPort: 8081


KEDA should start using the service account of your application instead of the default one.
Reference-
Federated Identity Credential
Keda on AKS
